# Need some guidance on how to set up directives for a dynamic view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on my first angular directive and still getting my head around the concepts and what's possible with directives. As I've been researching the best way to tackle this problem I haven't been able to identify an example that addresses what I'm trying to do, so thought I would ask for some help from the experts here.

I have an array of objects that are one of three types.

I would like to use the ng-repeat directive to iterate through this array and display the objects on the page.

Each object type has a different view associated with it as each object shares some properties, but also have unique properties.

I would like to set up a directive that displays the correct view based on the objective type.

So the logic would work something like the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in dataset">
    <the-smart-directive>item</the-smart-directive>
</div>
```

One idea would be to have one directive where I determine the templateUrl based on the object type and then have a unique template for each of the objects.

Another idea would be to have a parent directive and then three other directives (one for each object type) and the parent directive would insert the correct object type directive (this is the idea that seems like the better approach, but I'm not sure how to actually implement this idea).

I'd love some help in understanding the best way to tackle this and how to implement. If you could provide some example code that would be wonderful and get me started on the right path.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: actually numerous ways to do this ...directives are extremely powerful and flexible. Play with different parts of the directive is the best way to learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way we are using it is with ng-switch inside the ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in dataset" ng-switch="item.type">
        <directive-one ng-switch-when="1">
        </directive-one>
        <directive-two ng-switch-when="2">
        </directive-two>
        <directive-three ng-switch-when="3">
        </directive-three>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close to the "another idea" of a parent-directive calling the appropriate other directive.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but didn't realize that Angular already had something in place that I could leverage. Thank you!